# jQuery Multi-level/Accordion Side Menu Issue

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm trying to create a very simple `jQuery three-level menu`, however for some reason when trying to expand the 'third' level (sub-sub-menu) of the menu, the whole section is toggled, not just the third sub menu.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xa2dqqyo/

and the markup:

```
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Menu Link</a>
      <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Third Level</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

You can recreate it by clicking the sub link in the jsfiddle - it does toggle the third level, but it also toggles the whole menu/section.

Am I missing something simple here, or is the juery incorrect? For context, I'm working on a custom wordpress menu.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/xa2dqqyo/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu-item").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".sub-menu", this).slideToggle(300);
  });

  $(".sub-menu").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".sub-sub-menu", this).slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display:none;  
}
.sub-sub-menu {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a>
    <ul  class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Menu Link</a>
        <ul  class="sub-sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Third Level</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

You need to add `event.stopPropagation()`, to stop the event propagation.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu-item").click(function() {
        $(".sub-menu", this).slideToggle(300);
    });

    $(".sub-menu").click(function() {
        $(".sub-sub-menu", this).slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display:none;  
}
.sub-sub-menu {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sub Menu Link</a>
            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Third Level</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Isn't the answers are same? Is it really required to have duplicate the answer?

Comment: @Shiladitya, I think i was late but yes answer updated :-)